# Ajax call bug with Chrome new version 73.0.3683.75?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

My code was working fine before the Chrome update.

I make an ajax call to my server. My server receives the call, returns JSON to the client, but the answer is always empty. When I look in Fiddler I get an answer from the server.

[image]

I try with JQuery, and I also try with an xmlhttp call. Always the same result

Did new CORS policy rules apply...?

There is my xmlHTTP call

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
      var theUrl = "URL";
      xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      xmlhttp.send('{ "args" :{ "Obj":"my obj"}}');
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(state,xhh,aaa){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
```

The ajax call is similar

```
$.ajax({
        url: "URL",
        data: '{ "args" :{ "Obj":"my obj"}}',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,       
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          if (that.Fail != null) {
            that.Fail();
          }
        },
        success : function(data){

           alert(data);

        }
      })
```

Comment: Are you making the request in a content script? If so, does it help if you make it from a background script? Otherwise this sounds like a bug, see if disabling ”Network Service” in chrome://flags helps.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes i am in then content script. I will try to put my script in the background scripts.

Comment: I realise that it's look like a little bit weird. For security reason they don't let you create call from content.js. The security issue, it's probably more when you send data, than you received. My call was made correctly, it's the answer i am not able to get back. If i am an "hacker" i don't care about the answer, my priority should be send data, not retreived it from my server ... i don't understand the move here ... That update broke our Chrome extension and give us a lot of JOB :-(

Comment: You can send data by making a GET request - simply put the data in the URL hash or its query parameter. An URL can be 2MB long.

Comment: @wOxxOm ya you are right. That it's my point, why they  don't just block all CORB request from content.js instead only received the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrade to Chrome 73. Thanks to @wOxxOm

This is the workaround until now:

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. Disabled the **Enable network service**

[image: Step by step]

---

**UPDATE:**

This is not a bug, according to this announcement: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

You will need to put the Cross-Origin Fetches to the background script instead of the content script.

Comment: Thanks guy for you quick answer. Very useful. That was my problem! I move my ajax call that in the background.js and now it's work. Give me some job to move all the call made in the content.js to the background.js but ... i am on the right way!