# How can I remove the CORB warning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

Chrome was working until version 73. Now it is throwing me a CORB warning and stopping my chrome extension from running.

Here is my ajax jquery code, nothing special

```
  $.ajax({
    url: this.url + "api/users",
    type: 'get',
    data: { account_id: this.account_id(), user_id: this.user_id(), person_id: person_id },
    success: function (data) {
      //do stuff
    }
});
```

I did notice that if I remove the x-content-type-options header so that it no longer reads "nosniff" I can get some Ajax requests to be returned but not others. Not sure if this means anything but I noticed that the json requests that returned an array worked but others did not.

```
remove_keys = %w(X-Content-Type-Options)
response.headers.delete_if{|key| remove_keys.include? key}

[{'id' : '123'}] <-worked
{'id' : '123'} <- did not work (not sure if means anything)
```

Full error from chrome

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://ideas.test/api/users?token=W9BDdoiKcXLWSHXWySnwdCV69jz2y&account_id=3098355&user_id=john%40gmail.com&person_id=21046915&sync=false&new=true with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Headers from response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-auth_token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://mhikhjencpecbhelhjgdcgpdhlhdlhjh
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Origin: chrome-extension://mhikhjencpecbhelhjgdcgpdhlhdlhjh
Referer: https://3.basecamp.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36
```

How can I get the response body to be returned without chrome removing the body due to CORB?

Comment: I have the same issue with my extension as well, it's probably coming real thing for extenstions that use external API...

Comment: Hi, did you fix this? Currently I'm running Chrome on OSX using: open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir .........This solves the issue, But I'd prefer not doing it this way.

Comment: Okay I resolved mine by adding Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in my .htaccess. I wonder how I would restrict it specifically to https://mail.google.com. Tried replacing * with https://mail.google.com - didn't work.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153888/ajax-call-bug-with-chrome-new-version-73-0-3683-75 and https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. Might be an overkill for someone, but it took me 15 mins to fix everythiung. In your content script wrap all your ajax calls into a function:

Add ajaxGet function to your content script:

```
function ajaxGet(data){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'ajaxGet', data: data}, function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            if(response&&!response.statusText){//Might need some work here
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(response)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And in your background.js add a listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   if(request.action=="ajaxGet"){
       $.ajax(request.data).then(sendResponse,sendResponse)
       return true //telling chrome to wait till your ajax call resolves
   }
})
```

in stead of

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.url + "api/user_boards",
    type: 'get',
    data: { account_id: this.account_id()}
})
```

call

```
ajaxGet({
    url: this.url + "api/user_boards",
    type: 'get',
    data: { account_id: this.account_id()}
}).then(onSuccess, onError) //handle response from here
```

If you don't want to use jquery in your background.js you can make Xhr call in stead. Something like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(false);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    sendResponse(this.responseText)
  } else {
    //handle errors
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", request.data.url);

xhr.send(data);
```

You'll have to work around headers on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're putting the CORS headers in the request. You need to put them in the response instead.

Comment: You mean from that last header section? Sorry I believe those are actually the response headers. You can see from the ajax request im not putting any headers in the request.

Comment: @JohnPollard Those (`User-Agent`, `Referer`, etc.) are definitely request headers.

Comment: You're right that some of them are. I fixed the code. Sorry Its been a long day trying to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 73 inject some new security. Just try to move your xHTTP requests to your background script with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and get response with `SendResponse` callback.

In content or popup script replace ajax with :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  { action: "check", data: {/* params for url */}}, 
  // callback with url response
  function(response) {
    if( response.success ) {
      var myDataFromUrl = response.data;
      ...
    } else {
      console.log('Error with `check`,', response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

From background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var url = 'https://mysyte.com/';
    if(request.action === 'check' ) {
      url = url + 'check'
      ajax( url, request.data, 
        success: function( d ) {
          sendResponse({success: true, data: d});
        },
        error : function( d ) {
          sendResponse({success: false, data: d});
        }
      );
    }
});

function ajax( url, params, cbSuccess, cbError ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the CSP  & CORS issues, I was still getting the warning on the OPTIONS method call (which is done for cross-domain calls).

I fixed it on the server by setting the content-type for the OPTIONS method call (which doesn't return any data) to "application/octet-stream".  No more warnings!